# Uniform convergence of a complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, compactness, uniform-convergence, complex-integration

Let E a compact in the complex plane and U his complement that is connected.
Let μ a complex measure on the boundary of U.
I don't undestand why the integral of |1/(z-t)|dμ(t) in boundary of U converges in a.e in the plane. (hint:Fubini's theorem)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For $r>0,$ is

$$\int_{\{|z| < r\}}\int_{\partial U}\frac{1}{|\zeta - z|}\,d|\mu|(\zeta)\, dm_2(z) < \infty?$$

Here $m_2$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb C.$

Comment: Form this fact there is absolute convergente in the plane?

Comment: Can you say why under the same ipothesis the integral ∫ log |(z-ζ)|dμ(ζ) on E converges absolutely a.e. in the plane?

Comment: @Giacomo Yes to both questions.